# Sound issue on 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: sound, 64-bit

The sound isn't working when I try to play anything in a player or the sound in a game. Sounds in the browser work however. I did the Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting up to `aptitude --purge reinstall`, but that didn't change anything.

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lsmod | grep snd`

```
snd_seq_dummy          12798  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     28167  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   336771  1 
snd_hda_intel          33176  3 
snd_hda_codec         103804  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13604  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96391  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30486  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61621  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29602  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14462  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    67382  15    
snd_hda_codec_hdmi, snd_hda_codec_realtek, snd_hda_intel, snd_hda_codec, snd_hwdep, 
    snd_pcm, snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

`lspci -v | grep -iA7 audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0455
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at f0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

--
02:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan HDMI Audio [Mobility Radeon HD  5000 Series]
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0455
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at cfedc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

LE: This is the output I get when running the alsa-info.sh script. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/546032/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from having two sound cards, an on-board one and one that came with the video card. Deactivating the latter made the sound work.